# Getting the color of a UIView during an animation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, colors

I'm using an animation to fade a button between two colors, and need to get its current color when the button is pressed.

Here's the animation code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(speed, delay: 0.0, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse, UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut], animations: {
            targetView.layer.backgroundColor = self.randomColors(40).CGColor
            targetView.layer.backgroundColor = self.randomColors(250).CGColor

            }, completion: nil)
```

Reading the color using `targetView.layer.backgroundColor` gives me the same result each time, not the color at that specific moment. I've tried a few functions to get the color of a specific pixel on screen to no avail either, they just return the same color each time.

The animation doesn't need to continue after the button is pressed, I just need to get the color at the point the button is pressed.

Any help would be amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`presentationLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer) to get an approximation of the on-screen state of a given layer, including any currently running animations. It returns an optional `AnyObject` – so you'll have to make sure you unwrap it correctly.

For example:

```
if let presentationLayer = targetView.layer.presentationLayer() as? CALayer {   
    let currentBackgroundColor = presentationLayer.backgroundColor
}
```

Note that the layer returned from this is a copy – and therefore any modifications to it won't be reflected anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you! That did exactly what I was after. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Stephen happy to help :)